# Laravel - Selecting data from two different tables to show on blade.html

Tags: php, laravel

On my index.blade i like to show two different sets of data, one is a list of computers the other one list of categories. two different type of data. in my controller I have

```
public function index()
{
    // Select data from table assets
    $assets = DB::table('assets')->where('status', '1')->orderBy('type', 'asc')->paginate(10);    //pass all the employees to a Var and send it to our page using "with" also puts page # at the bottom
    //select data from table  assetrefs
    $categories = DB::table('assetrefs')->get();
    //bind data and send using 'with'
    return view('assets.index')->with('assets', $assets)->with('categories', $categories);

}
```

on my view side I have these two loops

```
@if(count($categories) > 1)
    @foreach($categories as $row)
        {!!Form::open(['action' => ['AssetsController@showType', $row->title], 'method'=> 'POST', 'class'=> 'pull-left'])!!}
            {{Form::submit('Show '. $row->title, ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
        {!!Form::close()!!}
    @endforeach

@else
    <p> no content </p>
@endif
```

This shows a bunch of button with categories

```
    <div class="well"></div>

<!-- lists all the available assets in a div all types are mixed but sorted -->
@if(count($assets) > 1)
    @foreach($assets as $asset)
        <div class="well">
            <h3>{{$asset->type}}, {{$asset->make}} - {{$asset->model}} </h3>
            <small> {{$asset->sn}}</small>
            <small> <a href="/asset/{{$asset->id}}">View this account</a></small>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    {{$assets->links()}}

@else
    <p> no content </p>
@endif
```

this shows a list of all computers

When I load the page I get

```
2/2 ErrorException
Undefined variable: categories (View: resources\views\assets\index.blade.php)
```

Comment: can you post your complete stack trace

Comment: I think, since `view()` function accepts only 2 arguments, try to pass an array of data in single `with()` method.  `->with(['assets'=>$assets,'categories' => $categories])`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please pass data to view by making use of array instead of with like below:

```
public function index()
{
  // passing data without with
  $data['assets'] = DB::table('assets')->where('status', '1')->orderBy('type', 'asc')->paginate(10); 

  $data['categories'] = DB::table('assetrefs')->get();

  return view('assets.index',$data);

  // in case if you want to use with then
  // return view('assets.index')->with($data);

}
```

Or even if you don't want to use $data variable want to keep $asset and $categories variable as it is then

```
public function index()
{
  // passing data without with
  $assets = DB::table('assets')->where('status', '1')->orderBy('type', 'asc')->paginate(10); 

  $categories = DB::table('assetrefs')->get();

  return view('assets.index',compact('assets','categories'));

}
```

You can check how compact function is working in php by url -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Comment: I originally used compact instead of with, same issue. I just thought to try using with instead, but didn't work

Comment: Can you add die or dd statement to your index function and check whether script is halting or not? and please show you route also

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Controller in place of your view() call:

```
 return view('assets.index', compact('assets', 'categories'));
```

Have a look at [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views) and you'll see `view()->with()` is suited for passing individual pieces of data whereas passing an array as a second argument is required for multiple variables. Here we're passing an array of your already defined `assets` and `categories` via PHP's [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function.

Comment: I originally used compact instead of with, same issue. I just thought to try using with instead, but didn't work

Comment: perhaps a different controller is being called?